# iOS NewsStand SDK/Framework

Tags: ipad, newsstand-kit

I am trying to find out how to create magazines for the iPad using NewsStand, I have read through all the info on the Apple developer website but cannot find a link to download the NewsStand SDK/Framework?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [iOS Newsstand Tutorial](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to download anything if you have downloaded latest XCode and iOS SDK. NS framework is part of iOS 5 SDK just include it in your project as you do for other frameworks.